# What kind of model should I use: dependent variable is proportion and test variables are dummy variables?

Tags: regression, generalized-least-squares

My dependent variable is percentage (0%~100%). My tests variables are two dummy variables. It seems that I cannot use regression directly. I read several materials, but they have different suggestions.

Some suggest GLS, because the dependent variable is proportion (percentage between 0%~100%). Some suggest Tobit model, because the dependent variable is truncated (between 1 and 0) and with many zeros. Some suggest Beta regression.

How do I choice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you interested in? What is it that you would like to model?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to try a GLM (Generalized Linear Model). Here is the link (http://data.princeton.edu/R/glms.html) for some details.